# Opening a file with space from Ruby

Tags: escape-characters, ruby

When I need to progmatically open in emacs a file that has a space in its name, how can I do that? I've tried these commands from a Ruby script, inside backquotes or `popen(…)`:

```
emacs "foo bar"
```

or

```
emacs foo\ bar
```

opens two files each named `foo` and `bar`, but I want to open a file named `foo bar`.

Comment: For me, typing `emacs "foo bar" RETURN`, typing some garbage followed by `C-x C-s` creates a file called `foo bar`.  `emacs foo\ bar RETURN` also works.  My shell is `bash`.  If the shell or emacs is behaving differently for you, then there's something in your environment that is causing it.

Comment: What do you mean by "programatically open" the file?  You're calling emacs in a script?  If so, can you show the relevant bits of the script?

Comment: @cjc It is just what I showed above surrounded with backticks, or those string put inside a Ruby script `popen(...)`.

Comment: @KyleJones I am not directly typing the commands in emacs or in a shell. I have a script in Ruby and I embedded the codes above within backticks or `popen(...)`.

Comment: In that case, this is more of a Ruby question, and how Ruby deals with escape characters, than strictly a Unix/Linux question.  Post it to Stackoverflow?

Comment: If this is a Ruby question, you need to show the Ruby code you're using to invoke emacs.

Comment: Thanks. I though I had escaped, but the escaping was not enough. Now, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're having problems with quoting because you're calling popen with a commandline, which is passed to the shell.  Ruby's string parser is either eating the double quotes or eating the backslash.  You can either call popen with an array of strings, which will bypass the shell, or you can write `emacs foo\\ bar` which will escape the backslash that you want Ruby to leave for the shell to see.